# Does the vanishing of $\mathrm{Ext}^i_G(\rho,\pi)$ for every irreducible $\pi$ implies the same vanishing for more general representations $\pi$?

Tags: representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, locally-compact-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-adic group, i.e., the group of $E$-points of some connected reductive group over a $p$-adic local field $E$. Let $\mathrm{Irr}(G)$ denote the set of equivalence classes of smooth irreducible representations of $G$. Assume that we are given some $\rho \in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$ such that, for some $i_0\geq 1$, we have
$$\forall i\geq i_0, \forall \pi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G),\quad \mathrm{Ext}^i_G(\rho,\pi) = 0.$$

Does it follow that $\mathrm{Ext}^i_G(\rho,\pi) = 0$ for $i\geq i_0$ and for any smooth representation $\pi$ of $G$?

By induction, the statement holds if $\pi$ has finite length as a $G$-module. However, I fail to solve the case of more general $\pi$. Even the case of finitely generated $\pi$ seems unclear, and I can't produce a concrete counterexample either.

Comment: I’m not sure at all, but since $\rho$ is irreducible, won’t $\mathrm{Ext}^{\cdot}_G(\rho,-)$ commute to colimits?

Comment: @Aphelli I think it is reasonable to expect that $\mathrm{Ext}_G^{\bullet}(\rho,\cdot)$ commutes with colimits. Do you suggest that one may use colimits to answer the question?

Comment: I was thinking that general smooth representations would be colimits of finite length smooth representations? Just like any $R$-module is a colimit of finitely generated modules?

Comment: @Aphelli I guess that the analogue would be that smooth representations are colimits of their finitely generated submodules, then? Not necessarily of finite length.

Comment: So you can have a smooth finitely generated submodule which has infinite length?

Comment: @Aphelli Well yeah, things like $\pi = \mathrm{c-Ind}_K^G \, \mathbb C = \bigoplus_{g\in G/K} g\mathbb C$, the compact induction of the trivial representation from an open compact subgroup $K$ to $G$. It is generated by a single vector (as a $G$-representation), but it does not have finite length in general. Eg. if $G = \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ and $K = \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z_p)$, the irreducible quotients of $\pi$ are all the unramified representations of $G$ by Frobenius reciprocity.